# Python 3 wave module byteorder..?

Tags: python, audio, wave

[Edit: In summary, this question was the result of me making (clearly incorrect) assumptions about what endian means (I assumed it was 00000001 vs 10000000, i.e. reversing the bits, rather than the bytes). Many thanks @tripleee for clearing  up my confusion.]

As far as I can tell, the byte order of frames returned by the Python 3 wave module [1] (which I'll now refer to as pywave) isn't documented. I've had a look at the source code [2] [3], but haven't quite figured it out.

Firstly, it looks like pywave only supports 'RIFF' wave files [2]. 'RIFF' files use little endian; unsigned for 8 bit or lower bitrate, otherwise signed (two's complement).

However, it looks like pywave converts the bytes it reads from the file to sys.byteorder [2]:

```py
data = self._data_chunk.read(nframes * self._framesize)
if self._sampwidth != 1 and sys.byteorder == 'big':
    data = audioop.byteswap(data, self._sampwidth)
```

Except in the case of `sampwidth==1`, which corresponds to an 8 bit file. So 8 bit files aren't converted to sys.byteorder? Why would this be? (Maybe because they are unsigned?)

Currently my logic looks like:

```py
if sampwidth == 1:
    signed = False
    byteorder = 'little'
else:
    signed = True
    byteorder = sys.byteorder
```

Is this correct?

8 bit wav files are incredibly rare nowadays, so this isn't really a problem. But I would still like to find answers...

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html

[2] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/wave.py

[3] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/chunk.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A byte is a byte, little or big endian only makes sense for data which is more than one byte.

- `0xf0` is a single, 8-bit byte. The bits are `0x11110000` on any modern architecture. Without a sign bit, the range is 0 through 255 (8 bits of storage gets 2<sup>8</sup> possible values).
- `0xf0eb` is a 16-bit number which takes two 8-bit bytes to represent. This can be represented as

  - `0xf0 0xeb` big-endian (`0x11110000 0x11101011`), or
  - `0xeb 0xf0` little-endian (`0x11101011 0x11110000`)

  The range of possible values without a sign bit is 0 through 65,535 (2<sup>16</sup> values).

You can also have different byte orders for 32-bit numbers etc, but I'll defer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) etc for the full exposition.